# Passing it a string, and running a python script from an html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

I've looked all over for a solution to this, but I've only managed to find the python half or the javascript half, and I need both.

I've got a python script that I run in the command line like so:

```
$ python3 myscript.py inputString
```

I want to be able to have users fill out a text box on a webpage, hit a button, and then have the python script run, given the string from the text box.

I've been told to run the python as a WGSI server, and have been told by others to use ajax such as:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/path/to/my/script.py",
    data: "document.getElementById('textinputID').value,
    success: function(response) {}
});
```

but I honestly don't understand ajax. especially the "success" part of that call. When I run just that jQuery I get errors, which maybe makes sense because I haven't done the server half of it?

I'm just very confused and would love it if someone could explain both halves in concert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to create a frontend client in javascript, and a backend python server. This is pretty basic stuff in web development.

I have created both sides of the app for you. Keep in mind that this is extremely basic.

First of all, you will use a python framework called [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). You have to installed it, like this:

```
> pip install flask
```

After that, create a file called `server.py`

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/script", methods=['POST'])
def script():
    input_string = request.form['data']

    """
    Your script code here
    """

    return "backend response"

@app.route('/')
def static_page():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`input_string` is the variable that will hold your input string.

Then, create a folder called `template` and add inside it a file called `index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <input id="textinputID" type="text" name="textinput">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function sendMessage() {
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: "http://localhost:5000/script",
                    data: {'data': document.getElementById('textinputID').value},
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response)
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        console.error(response)
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
        <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now you can run `python server.py` and you can go to `http://localhost:5000` in your browser.

The root will load `index.html`. When you **send** a text, you will be using `/script` endpoint. In there you can insert your script code. The response should be returned in that method.

*success* and *error* functions are callbacks. Those functions will trigger when the server send a response back. If the server return a HTTP status 2xx, the *success* function will be called; *error* otherwise.

I strongly recommend you read more about [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks). You can read more about this on [Flask site too](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I'm looking for. I also very much appreciate you explaining everything and adding follow-up links where I can do some research. It was difficult for me to understand seeing only one side, but now that I can see both it's much clearer.